# how grab field value from a PHP query (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Super new to PHP here, only using PHP to create my json data and having a hard time to understand the syntax. Here is some partial code:

All I am trying to do is to retrieve the value '2af8ddda-2be4-11e5-9453-b82a72d52c35' and put it in variable @sharepointID:

```
function selectWithSharepointID($table, $columns, $where){
try{
//Get Sharepoint file ID first
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM table1 ORDER BY DownloadedTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                
//$data[] = array("ID" => $rows['ID']);
//$sharepointID = $data[0];            
//$sharepointID = $rows[0];
$where   = array('id'=>$sharepointID);      
//$where = array('id'=>'2af8ddda-2be4-11e5-9453-b82a72d52c35'); //this works fine
...
```

PS: also tried to use print_r and echo but cant see anything in the console.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression returns array of rows:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So, you can get data from row 0 in your case:

```
$sharepointID = $rows[0]['ID'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `fetchAll` if you only have one record. Try:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM table1 ORDER BY DownloadedTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sharepointID = $row['ID'];
```

If you have multiple records the `fetchAll` makes sense but then you iterate through that to get each row, and its values.

For a rough example where I'd use `fetchAll`...

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name, userid FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
   echo 'Name: ' . $row['name'] . ' userid :' . $row['id'];
}
```